# My batch file doesn't create the excel file wanted

Tags: python

I created a batch file to run my python file in the task scheduler, but when I run my .bat file, it skips a loop that creates a excel file
this is the python code:

```
import os
import time
import shutil
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

current_path = pathlib.Path().cwd()
file_name = "Desktop\dossier_test"
root = os.path.join(pathlib.Path().cwd(),file_name)


def remove_files_by_modification_time(r):
    for i in os.listdir(r):
        path=os.path.join(r,i)
        if os.stat(path).st_mtime <=months:
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                os.remove(path)
            else:
                print ("impossible de supprimer")


results=[]
def show_folders_by_size(r):
    size_by_Mb = 0
    for ele in os.scandir(r):
        size_by_Mb+=os.path.getsize(ele)
    size_by_Mb=size_by_Mb//1048576
    path=r
    results.append(dict(path=path, size_by_Mb=size_by_Mb))


months = time.time()-(3*2628000)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for dir in dirs:
        if ("back" in dir):
            path_back=os.path.join(root,dir)
            remove_files_by_modification_time(path_back)    
        elif ("dev" in dir):
            path_dev=os.path.join(root,dir)
            show_folders_by_size(path_dev)
            resultsDf=pd.DataFrame(results)
            resultsDf= resultsDf.sort_values(by=['size_by_Mb'], ascending=False)
            resultsDf.to_excel('C:\\Users\\mbarrech\\Desktop\\folders_by_size.xlsx', sheet_name='products by size in Mb', index=False)
```

this is the batch file i created:

```
C:\Users\mbarrech\Anaconda3\envs\testpy\python.exe C:\Users\mbarrech\filescleaning.py
pause
```

Comment: Where are you running the batch script from? (what directory?). It's likely that it's not "skipping" the loop, just that neither of the conditions in that loop are fulfilled and so nothing happens.

Comment: What's the CWD? If `root` doesn't exist, `os.walk()` will fail silently by default.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing. And if you run it in scheduler then write information in file or in `logging`

Comment: if you use `pathlib` then you can use `root = current_path / "Desktop\dossier_test"` instead of `os.path.join()`. And if you want to use `os.path` then you can use `os.getcwd()` instead of `pathlib.Path().cwd()`

Comment: @HPringles both my batch file and my test folder are on the desktop